# Karate tests pass or fail inconsistently

Tags: java, integration-testing, karate

I'm using Karate with Gradle, and have 8 feature files that test read / GET functionality for my Spring Boot API.

I'm seeing these tests fail in a way that feels quite random.
The failures are related to Authorisation somehow, but I can't see anything that's wrong on the face of it.

Here's an example,

This fails

```
Feature: Get Objectives

  Background:
    * url baseUrl
    * def objectiveEndpoint = '/objectives'
    * header Authorization = token

  Scenario: Get an Objective that exists

    Given path objectiveEndpoint + '/37376564-3139-6232-2d66-6631392d3466'
    When method GET
    Then status 200
    And match response contains { objectiveId: '37376564-3139-6232-2d66-6631392d3466' }
```

And this passes

```
Feature: Get Assessments

  Background:
    * url baseUrl
    * def assessmentEndpoint = '/assessments'
    * header Authorization = token

  Scenario: Get an assessment that exists

    Given path assessmentEndpoint + '/2900b695-d344-4bec-b25d-524f6b22a93a'
    When method GET
    Then status 200
    And match response contains { odiAssessmentId: '2900b695-d344-4bec-b25d-524f6b22a93a' }
```

The objective test fails due to a 401 with the following message:

```
com.intuit.karate.exception.KarateException: objectives-read.feature:12 - status code was: 401, expected: 200, response time: 74, url: http://localhost:8080/objectives/37376564-3139-6232-2d66-6631392d3466, response: {"path":"/objectives/37376564-3139-6232-2d66-6631392d3466","error":"Unauthorized","message":"Unauthorized","timestamp":"2020-06-02T08:04:57.231+0000","status":401}
```

The assessments test passes.

I'm getting a token by running an Authorisation feature, and storing the result from that into the token variable.

The Auth feature is:

```
Feature: Log In

  Background:
    * url 'https://$URL/oauth/token'
    * def localSecret = secret
    * def localClientId = clientId

  Scenario: Get token
    Given url 'https://$URL/oauth/token'
    And form field grant_type = 'client_credentials'
    And form field client_id = localClientId
    And form field client_secret = localSecret
    And form field audience = 'http://localhost:8080'
    When method post
    Then status 200
    And match response contains { access_token: '#string' }
    And def access_token = $.access_token
```

I then add the token to config, and pass it into each test like this:

```
var result = karate.callSingle('classpath:login.feature', config);
    config.token = 'Bearer ' + result.access_token;
```

I've confirmed that the token used in the above two features is valid. I've manually tested my API with the token printed in the output of the failed tests, and both of the above tests work fine when I recreate them in Postman. This doesn't feel like a problem with my API because if I rerun the test suite, the tests that fail differ, and on my CI I have a green build with these tests.

I'm experiencing the problem both when running test suites individually like this:

```
@Karate.Test
    Karate testAssessments() {
        return Karate.run().relativeTo(AssessmentsRunner.class);
    }
```

and when running all of my tests in parallel like this:

```
public class SpecTestParallel {
    public static void generateReport(String karateOutputPath) {
        Collection<File> jsonFiles = FileUtils.listFiles(new File(karateOutputPath), new String[]{"json"}, true);
        List<String> jsonPaths = new ArrayList(jsonFiles.size());
        jsonFiles.forEach(file -> jsonPaths.add(file.getAbsolutePath()));
        Configuration config = new Configuration(new File("target"), "Test API");
        ReportBuilder reportBuilder = new ReportBuilder(jsonPaths, config);
        reportBuilder.generateReports();
    }

    @Test
    void testParallel() {
        Results results = Runner.path("classpath:specTests").tags("~@ignore").parallel(5);
        generateReport(results.getReportDir());
        assertEquals(0, results.getFailCount(), results.getErrorMessages());
    }
}
```

Has anyone had a similar issue before?

Comment: nope has to be something you are doing wrong. maybe you are using Java code not shown here which is not thread safe. nothing anyone can do from looking at this code, for any chance of a resolution (or helping us narrow down a bug fix) please follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, this was unexpected behaviour in IntelliJ.

So Karate appears to have a retry policy. If a test failes, it will retry a few times.

When I run tests using the test runner function in IntelliJ, each time a test fails, IntelliJ logs that in the test runner window as it should for a failed test, but Karate keeps running, retries and the test passes. I can see that in the reports now but the IntelliJ test runner doesn't update.

This leads to a confusing situation where tests pass, but appear to fail locally, but the tests pass on CI.

Here is an example of local tests:

[image: local-tests]

and the same commit passing in CI:

[image: ci-tests]

I'm not really sure what the fix is here, if there is one. It would be nice if IntelliJ was aware of this behaviour, or maybe Karate could only report the result of a test after all retries have been processed - right now it looks like Karate reports as soon as the first test run is processed.

It's been a confusing few days.

Comment: are you on JUnit 5, can you please upgrade to 0.9.6.RC3 and try, there's a (slight) chance this is fixed by: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/1150